# Mark and Unmark legend in QGIS 2.8.6

Tags: qgis, legend

I'm working in **QGIS 2.8.6** with layers with legends with many entries.Is it possible to mark or unmark elements of the legend with a single click?

[image: legend]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Categorized Symbology, you cannot select values and uncheck them at once to hide them from the legend. However, you can use Rule-Based to create a rule that act as a Group Layer, then you drag and drop into that Group Layer the legends that you want to hide by uncheck the Group Layer.

[image]

Add a new rule name it Group Layer Or any name you like.

[image]

Uncheck Group layer and "else" and click apply

[image]